# Select const value using query expression

Tags: c#, linq, query-expressions

How can I implement this query by query expression or method expression:

```
Select 1, a.Id 
From a
Where a.code = x
```

Comment: Please, share the code which you've tried to solve a problem

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/walkthrough-writing-queries-linq#to-transform-or-project-in-the-select-clauses) please

Comment: It was there. thanks @GuruStron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var data = a.Where(a => a.code == x).Select(a => new { Constant = 1, a.Id });
```